# Linq to SQL database context management

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have a question about managing the life cycle of a LINQ to SQL database context. Currently, I am using a factory to instantiate a new database context whenever one is required. Which is fine in some instances but not so during others. For example, when a single operation spans across multiple methods, in each method I am calling the factory to generate a new instance while I really need to share the context among the methods during the lifetime of the operation. In theory, the operation needs to be atomic. So, my question is to know whether is it a good design to have multiple factory methods in the factory to get the required context when required?

I have provided an example implementation below.

// interface

```
public interface IEntityContextFactory : ISingletonService
{
    IDbContext CreateContext();

    IDbContext GetContext();
}
```

// factory class

```
public class EntityContextFactory : IEntityContextFactory
{
    private IDbContext _context;

    public IDbContext CreateContext()
    {
        var defaultConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection_name"].ConnectionString;
        var database = new DataContext(defaultConnectionString);
        // this is a wrapper around the linq to sql context
        return new DbContext(database);
    }

    public IDbContext GetContext()
    {
        // TODO: make threadsafe
        if(_context == null)
        {
            _context = CreateContext();
            return _context;
        }

        return _context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) in your methods.

A method that demands a context should receive one, rather than receiving the ability to "new up" its own --even from a factory that appears to be doing the same thing.

If the methods can be organized reasonably into a class then that class' constructor can demand the context to use.

Finally, and this is the really important part, it sounds like you want to wrap up methods that will need the *same* context within a new method (or methods) that can leverage your factory.

A hasty example.

```
public class DataAccess {

    private IDbContext _dbContext;

    public DataAccess(IDbContext context) {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    // atomic example
    public UserModel GetUser(int id) {
        return _dbContext.UserTable
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    // not-atomic example
    public bool RecordUserActivity(UserModel user, IEnumerable<UserActivity> activities) {
        try {
            _dbContext.BeginTransaction();

            // messy example
            _dbContext.UserLogins
                .Add(activities.Where(x => x.ActivityType == ActivityTypes.Logins));
            _dbContext.UserEdits
                .Add(activities.Where(x => x.ActivityType == ActivityTypes.Edits));
            // 

            _dbContext.CommitTransaction();
            return true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log your exceptions!
            _dbContext.RollbackTransaction();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @clarkitect. Currently, I am injecting the factory to the classes and a method in a class can request for the context via the factory. But what you are proposing is rather to inject the context itself. Understand this will solve the fundamental problem but won't this lead sharing the same instance everywhere?